# Read-quota in firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a pretty simple use-case:

I have a simple app with questions (stored in firestore), and I want users to be able to filter on the questions before they start an exercise.

Right now it's just 100 questions, (but could eventually grow to 1000+)
Some days I have 100+ users, (but could eventually grow to 1000+)

To filter the questions I get all questions from firestore:

```
const fetchAllQuestions = async (): Promise<Question[]> => {
  const q = query(collection(fireStore, "questions"));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const questions: any = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => questions.push(doc.data()));
  return questions as Question[];
};
```

and then I apply the filter.

But this is one document-read per user and question so 100 questions and 100 users becomes 10000 document reads, eating up the quota in just 5 days. And that is a best case scenario without any page-reloads or cache-invalidations.

And even less viable if the page grows in content and usage.

Since "filtering on just a subset of questions" isn't an option I see some ways of bypassing this:

a) Caching the result in local-storage, this would cover page reloads and return visitors but I'd need to invalidate the storage-key when updating the questions, and I'd still reach the quote after 500 unique visitors.

Plus, it feels like a "hack".

b) Just put ALL the questions in one single document, or chop them up and have 100 per document or something similar. This would basically solve the problem since I'm not fetching single questions anyway. Uploading questions would be slightly more cumbersome since I need to fetch the whole bunch, then update the question and then upload the whole lot as one big document.

Still, it also feels slightly like a "hack".

So I can't help but feel like there's something I'm missing here, some "idiomatic" firestore-way of handling this use case that I must have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should

1. Save your questions as JSON and making sure you are saving its keywords or tags so that you can filter your questions according to tags. In your app you can just display thoses tags and make user click on them to filter
2. Ok, saving in chunks per documents is not stable i think since, you may not know how to query them properly
3. Then you can use cursors to fetch your questions per page: follow this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: 1. I am saving my questions as json (with fields like id, image, tags, category, etc). A user should be able to query "all questions I've done" which they have in their local storage. perhaps I could do specific queries on "all of these ID:s"? Would increase complexity but could work.

But now that I read more about queries it looks like I could do a lot of the filtering through a query.

Comment: Then again I still have problems like: If a user haven't filtered at all, I still show a preview ie. "You've currently selected 112 questions, it should take 132 minutes, 30% are type-A 70% are type-b" etc. and to show that "preview"-info I'd need to fetch them all.

Comment: Firestore is very limited. And you are feeling to expense a lot because it is pay as you go. If you were using another NoSql database charged on subscription you could be charged maybe more than 5 USD per month for small project. Now imagine 5 USD on firestore, it is a lot. Just use cursors